# Why can't I use softmax in regression task for probabilities?

Tags: keras, regression, probability, softmax

I have a supervised learning task f(X)=y where X is a 2-dimentional np.array of np.int8 and y is a 1-dimentional array of np.float64 containing **probabilities** (so numbers between 0 and 1). I want to build a Neural Network model that performs regression in order to predict said probabilities y given X.

As the output of my Network is one real value (i.e. the output layer has one neuron) and is a probability (so in the range [0, 1]), I believe I should use softmax as the activation function of the output layer (i.e. output neuron) in order to squash the network's output to [0, 1].

As it is a regression task, I opted for using the mean_squared_error loss (instead of cross_entropy_loss that is typically used in classification tasks and often paired with softmax).

However, as I am trying to fit(X, y) the loss does not change at all between epochs and remains constant. Any ideas why? Is the combination of softmax and mean_squared_error loss wrong for some reason and why?

If I remove the softmax it does work, but then my model would also predict non probabilities which I do not want. Yes, I could squash it myself later but it doesn't seem right.

My code basically is (after removing some irrelevant additional callbacks for EarlyStopping and learning rate scheaduling):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(W1_size, input_shape=(input_dims,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
# compile model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mse')   # mse is the standard loss for regression
# fit
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS)
```

Edit: Turns out I needed the sigmoid function to squash one real value to [0, 1] as the accepted answer suggests. The softmax function for a vector of size 1 is always 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated you want to perform a `regression task`. (Which means, finding a continuous mapping between your input and desired output).
The `softmax` function creates a pseudo-probability distribution for multi-dimensional outputs (all values sum up to `1`). This is the reason why the `softmax` function perfectly fits for `classification tasks` (predicting probabilities for different classes).

As you want to perform a `regression task` and your output is one-dimensional, softmax would not work properly because it is always `1` for a one-dimensional input.
A function which maps a one-dimensional input continuously to [0,1] works fine here (e.g Sigmoid).

Note that you can also interpret both the output of the `sigmoid` and the `softmax` function as probabilities. But be careful: these are only pseudo-probabilities and it is not representing the certainty or uncertainty of your model in making predictions.